# Dapr pubsub with redis

Tags: redis, architecture, publish-subscribe, dapr

With Dapr pub-sub using redis can we limit the rate/interval at which dapr will check if there is a new message in redis? I have been looking for a way to limit that in the yaml file. Here is a sample of the yaml file for you to review.

```yaml
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: orderpubsub
spec:
  type: pubsub.redis
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: redisHost
    value: localhost:6379
  - name: redisPassword
    value: ""
```